# Is it better one or more string.xml by App?

Tags: android, string

I'm developing an app with more than 20 activities and the size of my strings.xml is growing up. I'm in doubts about which is the best choice, to use a single file for the whole app or create differents strings.xml linked to sets of Activities with common content...

What do you say?

Thanks

Comment: If it's any indication, I remember seeing a few sample projects from Google that all had massive string.xml files. It's not like it will really matter performance-wise (as far as I can tell), I'd just keep one big file. Format it properly, whichever way you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't worry about the size. I don't know all the technical mumbo-jumbo, but all the resources are indexed when it's compiled, so it won't affect speed either way.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about size or length. In the end its virtual machine whose gonna make R.class file which will contain all your layout and widgets reference.